# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be numeric: while using mice

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to impute missing values so I tried using the mice package. My data is as follow:

```
ID     Date        DayNum      Day       Hour       Transaction
1    07/01/16        1          6         0             20 
1    07/01/16        1          6         1             30
1    07/01/16        1          6         2             NA
1    07/01/16        1          6         3             NA
1    07/01/16        1          6         4             39
1    07/01/16        1          6         5             10
1    07/01/16        1          6         6             54
```

As you can see that I have NA values and would like to impute them using the mice package in R.

Assuming my data frame is called df1 I entered the following code and I got an error

```
imputed_Data <- mice(df1, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
summary(imputed_Data) 

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be numeric
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Also Note: Daynum and Day are of no use to me so I will remove them later.

```
ID   Date     Hour Transaction
1  2016-07-01  4   62
1  2016-07-01  5   78
1  2016-07-01  6   879
1  2016-07-01  7   67
1  2016-07-01  8   10
1  2016-07-01  9   11
1  2016-07-01  10  14
1  2016-07-01  11  NA
```

Comment: Can you add `dput(yourdataframe[1:5, 1:5])` please.

Comment: I did remove those columns. and i tried your method of dput. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you edit your question with the results of `dput(yourdataframe[1:5, 1:5])` , this will allow us to see the data structure. cheers

Comment: Are you able to see it now?

Comment: The output of `str(df1)` may also help diagnose the problem. My guess is that one of those columns is being treated as character or factor (probably factor).

Comment: looks like Date is the only column that's in a date format. Others are all showing num.

Comment: @Abrar ; thanks, however, you have copied the first few rows from your screen: this can hide some issues in the data. Can you try to add the results of `dput(yourdataframe[1:5, 1:5])` as it is output, please

Comment: You should restrict either the data frame or the imputation model to include only the variables of interest. Otherwise, the imputation may not make much sense. Restricting the data frame/model will likely also solve your problem. As @Abrar pointed out, `mice` expects that all variables are `numeric`.

Comment: @SimonG i completely agree with you Simon. Thats what i did and it works. Thanks you all for the help.